# Iphone SE 2 : Dual SIM - Calling back from Secondary SIM (Incoming call received in Primary SIM)

Tags: iphone, sim, call, esim

Dual sim iphone calling primary call from secondary SIM

I have a Iphone SE 2 with (Primary - Physical SIM and Secondary - eSIM). When I try calling back the Missed calls/Incoming calls, I'm able to call back only on the same SIM. (i.e., If I'm missing a call in primary phone number, I'm seeing option to call back only from the primary phone number (same SIM). Vice Versa.).

I'd want to callback from my primary SIM, for the calls that are missed in secondary SIM. Is this possible?

Comment: One possibility is to create a contact for those numbers for which you can force usage of desired SIM.

Comment: Thanks for reply @PtitXav. Yes, Creating a new contact will help. But, As I'd be on travel most of the time, I tend to miss the call very easily. Saving all the numbers I miss would be difficult for me. Is there any other way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Anther way is to temporarily deactivate second SIM. And reactivate when finish calls.

Comment: @PtitXav, deactivate each time is again complex process. Is there any other way that you can think of?  This is seamless in android. Is this a restriction from Apple iphone?

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is: This is currently not possible. Very frustrating.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/327421)